# Is $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x}}$ converging or diverging?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

**Q:** $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x}}$ converges or diverges?

I found the solution using limit comparison test.

$$\lim_{x\to b-}(b-x)^p f(x)=\gamma$$

(1) $0\leq\gamma\lt\infty$ and $p\lt1 \Rightarrow \int_a^bf(x)dx$ converges.

(2) $0\lt\gamma\leq\infty$ and $p\ge1 \Rightarrow \int_a^bf(x)dx$ diverges.

My solution:

$\lim_{x\to 0+}x^{3/2}\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}=\lim_{x\to 0+}1=1$

So the given integral diverges due to (2).

Is my solution right? Because the theorem is defined by the upper limit of the integral which is $b$ and the limit is $x\to b-$.

Comment: It's all right !

Comment: Thanks for the check!

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, but not necessary to proceed this way, since you have the antiderivative from the formula
$$\int\frac{1}{x^n}\,\mathrm dx=-\frac 1{(n-1)x^{n-1}}+\text{ constant}.$$
In the present case, you get
$$\int_0^1\frac1{x^{3/2}}=\frac2{x^{1/2}}\Biggm|_1^0=+\infty.$$